# vlookup using Access VBA in an Excel sheet

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Excel workbook with two sheets which I exported from MS Access using VBA. Now I want to do a `VLookUp` between the two sheets and return the data in COLUMN A from sheet 1. How do I do that using Access VBA? Below is my code.

```
Private Sub Command1679_Click()
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "Query1", "C:\Blended Rate - Report\BR_Report" & "_" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx", True, "BRReport"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "Query2", "C:\Blended Rate - Report\BR_Report" & "_" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx", True, "RamReport"
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel's `VLookUp` returns values not whole columns based on criteria. Please illustrate with data your needs. Also why not just query in Access and export result to Excel?

Comment: I meant values, sorry about that. The source is from two different data source. So i cannot query in Access. In other words the first query **"qry - Int Alloc - Step 05 - Blended Rate Report"** has data in it. The second query **"qry - RAM RECON"** is just an empty query with only column name. Now the idea is to automate the reconciliation between the two data source. So the user pastes the data from another data source to the second sheet and I want to pre-code the vlookup in one of the columns in sheet 2 using VBA where it looks up the data from sheet 1 and catches the break.

Answer (score 0):

Using Excel functions in VBA code is not efficient and often very slow. Why don't you just made the calculation in Access before you export ?

Comment: The source is from two different data source. So i cannot do the calculation in Access. In other words the first query **"qry - Int Alloc - Step 05 - Blended Rate Report"** has data in it. The second query **"qry - RAM RECON"** is just an empty query with only column name. Now the idea is to automate the reconciliation between the two data source. So the user pastes the data from another data source to the second sheet and I want to pre-code the vlookup in one of the columns in sheet 2 using VBA where it looks up the data from sheet 1 and catches the break.

Comment: Have you tried to import your datas in Access tables ? You could use them as temporary tables for doing the operations.

Answer (score 0):

there is a function dlookup in access have you tried it.

Comment: How can I use Dlookup to reconcile (lookup) two columns in the excel sheet from access VBA?